# How do i add searchbar to my splitViewController in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, xcode4

In my app i have to include searchBar under navigationbar in my detailViewController. My detailViewController contains different views.
Now my question is how do i add searchbar to detailViewController and  where should i add searchBar?

Please suggest me the way to do this.
Thank you.

Comment: You can even do this from your `xib`!

Comment: hi, what you want to search ? do you want to search data from table view OR any thing else ?

Comment: HOW DO I questions do not fit our format, and WHERE questions belong on UX.

Comment: yes maulik  i want to search data from tableView and i have to open popViewController when i click on searchbar and my popView contains tableView

Comment: @ShwetaThakar: I think its better to keep your search bar with popViewController and perform search...

Comment: @ShwetaThakar: +1 Good Question. I think you can adding your UISearchBar to as `self.navigationitem.titleview`.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad of your detailViewController add this code

```
UIBarButtonItem *searchBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch 
                                                                               target:self 
                                                                               action:@selector(searchButtonAction:)];
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:searchBarButton animated:YES];
```